# Make unique id based on text data column with similarity scoring

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Dry Fish'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2]
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to identify similar names in `name` column if those names belong to one cluster number and create unique id for them. For example `South Beach` and `Beach` belong to cluster number `1` and their similarity score is pretty high. So we associate it with unique id, say `1`. Next cluster is number `2` and three entities from `name` column belong to this cluster: `Dog`, `Big Dog`, `Cat`, 'Fish' and 'Dry Fish'. `Dog` and `Big Dog` have high similarity score and their unique id will be, say `2`. For `Cat` unique id will be, say `3`. Finally for 'Fish' and 'Dry Fish' unique id will be, say `4`. And so on.

Here is my code:

```
# pip install thefuzz
from thefuzz import fuzz

df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_test['id'] = 0

i = 1
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    row_ = row
    index_ = index
    
    while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] and df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] == 0:
        if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
            df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
            is_i_used = True
        index_ += 1
        
    if is_i_used == True:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

Code generates the following result:

```
    name         cluster_number  id
0   Beach               1        1
1   South Beach         1        1
2   Big Dog             2        2
3   Cat                 2        3
4   Dog                 2        2
5   Dry Fish            2        4
6   Fish                2        4
7   Ant                 3        5
8   Bird                3        6
9   Dear                4        7
```

Any advises in code improvement are much appreciated

Comment: @pacmaninbw I changed the title of the question

Comment: Much improved - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like it is trying to create a new 'id' column in the DataFrame that groups names together if they belong to the same cluster and have a high similarity score.

There are a few issues with this code. First, the variable is_i_used is never defined. It is used in the code but never assigned a value. This will cause an error. Additionally, the code is not handling the case where two names belong to the same cluster but have a low similarity score. In this case, they would not be assigned the same 'id' value, but the code does not account for this.

Here is a modified version of the code that addresses these issues and should work as intended:

```py
# pip install thefuzz
from thefuzz import fuzz

df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_test['id'] = 0

i = 1
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    row_ = row
    index_ = index
    
    # Check if the current name has already been assigned an 'id' value.
    # If it has, we can skip it and move on to the next name.
    if row['id'] != 0:
        continue
    
    # Iterate through the remaining rows in the DataFrame
    # and assign the current 'id' value to any names that belong
    # to the same cluster and have a high similarity score.
    while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number']:
        if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
            df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
        index_ += 1
    
    # Increment the 'id' value for the next group of similar names.
    i += 1
```

This code should work as intended and assign unique 'id' values to groups of similar names within each cluster. Note that names that do not have a high enough similarity score to be grouped together will be assigned different 'id' values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You say: "the code is not handling the case where two names belong to the same cluster but have a low similarity score". Disagree. Code handles it in every first iteration in while loop because `index_ = index` for it so condition `row['name'] == df.loc[index_, 'name']` is `True`.  Also I was unable to generate correct id using your code.  For given `df_test `  it gives `id` in range of 1 to 10.

Comment: It looks like the issue with line: `if row['restaurant_id'] != 0:  continue`. It is needed to be change to `if df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] != 0:  continue` then your code will work.